# Count null columns as zeros with oracle

Tags: node.js, oracle

---

I am running a query with Oracle:

```
SELECT
    c.customer_number,
    COUNT(DISTINCT o.ORDER_NUMBER),
    COUNT(DISTINCT q.QUOTE_NUMBER)
FROM
    Customer c
    JOIN Orders o on c.customer_number = o.party_number
    JOIN Quote q on c.customer_number = q.account_number
GROUP BY
    c.customer_number
```

This works beautifully and I can get the customer and their order and quote counts.

However, not all customers have orders or quotes but I still want their data.  When I use `LEFT JOIN` I get this error from Oracle:

> ORA-24347: Warning of a NULL column in an aggregate function

Seemingly this error is caused by the eventual `COUNT(NULL)` for customers that are missing orders and/or quotes.

How can I get a `COUNT` of null values to come out to 0 in this query?

I can do `COUNT(DISTINCT NVL(o.ORDER_NUMBER, 0))` but then the counts will come out to `1` if orders/quotes are missing which is no good.  Using `NVL(o.ORDER_NUMBER, NULL)` has the same problem.

Comment: Try the `nvl` function. Usage `nvl(field, replace_with)`.

Comment: You're getting a warning not an error.  So long as you understand why you're getting the warning and so long as you understand (and desire) the behavior, your code with `left join` is perfectly valid.

Comment: @RodrigoMedeiros this sort of works but then I have `COUNT(DISTINCT 0)` which comes out to `1`

Comment: @JustinCave that would be okay with me ... I'm using https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb and it seems to treat this as an error.  Do you know if I can suppress the warning or still get it to return the values of the query to me in spite of it?  Right now I only get the error in the callback of the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using inline views:

```
SELECT
    c.customer_number,
    o.order_count,
    q.quote_count
FROM
    customer c,
    (   SELECT
            party_number,
            COUNT(DISTINCT order_number) AS order_count
        FROM
            orders
        GROUP BY
            party_number
    ) o,
    (   SELECT
            account_number,
            COUNT(DISTINCT quote_number) AS quote_count
        FROM
            quote
        GROUP BY
            account_number
    ) q
WHERE 1=1
    AND c.customer_number = o.party_number (+)
    AND c.customer_number = q.account_number (+)
;
```

Sorry, but I'm not working with any databases right now to test this, or to test whatever the ANSI SQL version might be.  Just going on memory.